# not able to downgrade from maven 3.5.2 to maven 3.0.4 : No available formula with the name "maven30"

Tags: maven, maven-3, homebrew

I have uninstalled maven using

`brew uninstall maven`

and tried to install it again using

`brew install maven30`

but I got this error

```
 brew install maven30
Error: No available formula with the name "maven30" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
==> Searching local taps...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: curl is not executable
```

however when I use `brew install maven` it got downloaded and installed as well

```
   brew install maven
==> Downloading https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=maven/maven-3/3.5.2/b
Already downloaded: /Users/amar/Library/Caches/Homebrew/maven-3.5.2.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.2: 104 files, 10.1MB, built in 3 seconds
```

so why I am getting `curl is not executable` in `maven30`

I also tried

```
 brew tap homebrew/versions
Warning: homebrew/versions was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.
```

Comment: You can always install your own maven.  It is just a matter of downloading and unzipping a file and either use the full name of the mvn command, or add it to  your path .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the `mvn` zip file for 3.0.4  from [here](https://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/) and then executed `mvn` command located in bin file as shown below

```
amar@admin:~/Downloads/apache-maven-3.0.4$ tree -L 2

    ├── LICENSE.txt
    ├── NOTICE.txt
    ├── README.txt
    ├── bin
    │   ├── m2.conf
    │   ├── mvn
    │   ├── mvn.bat
    │   ├── mvnDebug
    │   ├── mvnDebug.bat
    │   └── mvnyjp
```

Now go the bin folder and query for version

```
amar@admin:~/Downloads/apache-maven-3.0.4/bin$ ./mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 03:44:56-0500)
Maven home: /Users/amar/Downloads/apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.8.0_144, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_CA, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.13.2", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Now it is working fine, another step is to uninstall the current version and unlink it as well using `brew uninstall maven` and `brew unlink maven`

now you can add the path of your current maven binary in  `bash_profile` and sourced it. below is the example

```
export M2_HOME=/Users/amar/Downloads/apache-maven-3.0.4
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

try checking version again, it worked for me

```
amar@admin:~$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 03:44:56-0500)
Maven home: /Users/amar/Downloads/apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.8.0_144, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_CA, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.13.2", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
amar@admin:~$
```